Apache Superset Show Values Font-Size Arrangement
I'd like to be able to modify the font-size of "Show Values" and "Axis Values". Could you please help me with that? Edit CSS Template option is the only way to modify Apache Superset Dashboards as far as I know. But when I inspect it the whole chart is in a canvas form where I cannot further inspect the elements that comprises it. Making the marked values' font size bigger is pivotal for my dashboard so that it can be readed with an ease. I expect all your help, thanks in advance.
Screenshot
I tried using CSS code but I cannot further inspect the values' elements to find its class and write it in CSS format.
